# Mapping User-ID and source/medium/campaign

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I'm trying to create a report from my Google Analytics data, which maps user-ids with the source / medium / campaign.

So think something like the table you find in the User Explorer, except with the columns : user-id | source | medium | campaign.

This doesn't seem to be obviously available and I couldn't find anything useful via google search. What I've found deals with the user-id or the campaign, never both together :/

Ideally the resulting table would be exportable. Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only send User ID in the userId field, it disappears into the depths of GA never to be seen again (that is, it is used internally only, and is not available as a dimension in reports or segments).

If you want to access User ID for reporting, you need to send it in a custom dimension as well as in the userId. Here is some documentation that might be helpful: [Analytics custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828); [Analytics custom dimensions with Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164990).

After that, you could create a Flat Table type Custom Report with the custom dimension and the three Acquisition dimensions you're interested in (plus at least one metric; you always need a metric for reporting). The "export" button near the top right of the page will allow you to export the table as a PDF or spreadsheet - though it will only export what is currently visible, so show as many rows of the table as possible.

Comment: so basically what's the use of the user ID field? It's only used to map a user cross-devices in the User Explorer view? Doesn't seem to show up anywhere else

Comment: @JadS - basically yes, it is only used to connect cross-device. In a regular View it shows up in the Audience > Behavior > User-ID Coverage report and as the User-ID Status dimension. It can also affect your Users count and User-scope segments. You get more from a User ID View, though then there is only data for the sessions in which an ID was assigned (and you still can't get the ID itself).